# Excel rebooting while copying sheets from multiple books

Tags: excel, vba

I built a program to copy sheet one from all books in a directory, and paste them into the active workbook. I have roughly 1200 books in the directory, and without fail each time I run it excel reboots after around #125. No error messages. Anyway of getting around this?

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\bdaly\Desktop\Formulas\smaller sample\"
Dim DestWB As Workbook

Set DestWB = ThisWorkbook

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

     Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count)
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

     Filename = Left(Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 4), 31)
     DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count).Name = Filename
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Edit: As advised I removed the offending file, Excel still reboots after 124 loops.

Comment: Is it always the same file being processed when it restarts?

Comment: ^^ As above. Have you tried pinpointing the file in question? Then removing that file and seeing if runs?

Comment: Could it be that any of those XLS that you open trigger a macro that closes Excel. Try opening workbooks without activating macros. Use `Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True, Editable:=True` and tell us it it fails in same round (around #125)

Comment: OK guys, so I removed that file, and the excel still stalls out at number 125. It seems like for whatever reason the program can only loop 124 times.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210684/copying-worksheet-programmatically-causes-run-time-error-1004-in-excel

Comment: @hithenameisbj -- ***Excel doesn't reboot.*  Is your *computer* rebooting, or is Excel *crashing* or *shutting down* or *restarting*?**  And it gives *no error?*  Are you ***sure*** it's not even giving yoiu a "not responding" error (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0BE.png)?)     Details like this matter because different people interpret your incorrect terminology in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to address the problem at hand, but it will help in debugging or exposing the problem.
Put simply, qualify your source data.

1. Include `Dim SourceWB as Workbook`. This could be done where you declare `DestWB`.
2. Change `Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True` to `Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True, Editable:=True)`
3. Change `Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count)` to `SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count)`
4. Change `Workbooks(Filename).Close` to `SourceWB.Close`

Unfortunately, the `.Copy` command is a Sub, not a Function - would be so much more neater if it provided a reference to the sheet that has just been created as you could then use it in `DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count).Name = Filename`

I suggest, for debugging purposes, keeping the `DisplayAlerts` on for now. This may provide a clue as to where the fault is happening.

Also include some `debug.print` lines in your loop. Finding where in the loop it crashes could help diagnose the issue. Make them a little descriptive, the ones I would think of are:
`debug.print "Entered loop"`
`debug.print "Copied file"`
`debug.print` "renamed file"
`'debug.print` "new FileName is " & FileName`.
You get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try the AddIn from the link below.

[image]

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm